# Writing Mocha Test Specs for front end component (react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, mocha.js, frontend

I am having so much trouble writing mocha test specs for my front end components.
My component look really simple, but just have no clue how to write test specs.
Could someone please help me with this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

```js
import React from 'react';

//Submit handler takes the message and gives it to the callback of its parent component, ChatApp for rendering and emitting to server
//Keep track of the mssage when you type and assign it to a property (text) in state
class MessageForm extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  this.state = {text: ''}
 }

 handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var message = {
   user: this.props.user,
   text: this.state.text,
   language: this.props.language,
   id: 1
  }
  //Connects to ChatApp component
  this.props.onMessageSubmit(message);
  //Set the state of the text to empty string so that next inputted text value can be hanled in the state
  this.setState({ text: '' })
 }

 changeHandler(e) {
  //change the state of text to inputted value
  this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <div className="message_form">
    <h3>Write New Message</h3>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
     <input
      onChange={this.changeHandler}
      value={this.state.text}
      placeholder='Write new message'
     />
    </form>
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default MessageForm;
```

Comment: It would be good to provide submit button.

Answer (score 0):

With `enzyme` and `sinon` you can do something like this:

```
it("submits message", () => {
    // GIVEN
    const submitCallback = sinon.spy();
    const actualNode = shallow(<MessageForm onMessageSubmit={submitCallback} />);

    // WHEN
    actualNode.find("input").simulate("change", { target: { value: "Test Message" } });
    actualNode.find("form").simulate("submit");

    // THEN
    sinon.assert.calledWith(submitCallback, "Test Message");
});
```

This is just basic interactivity test. You can also create test to verify HTML rendering and state transitions. Look into `enzyme` docs to get more info.